# Can we run Jmeter test from different geo location simultaneously?

Tags: websocket, jmeter, load

Can we run Jmeter test from different geo location simultaneously? I want to run laod test for a gaming application,so users have to be generated from different client locations(UK,US) to hit the server simultneously.players from  different geolocations should  hit the server at the same time.How to do that using Jmeter???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend using JMeter distributed testing for that as it is more suitable that jmeter client and servers are in same LAN.

So you have 2 options at least:

- orchestrate the running of autonomous JMeter instances using ansible or similar tools
- Use a Paas like [Redline13](https://www.redline13.com) that will allow you to easily do that using AWS with benefit of having all the JMeter setup done and have live aggregated report and final aggregated CSV and JMeter HTML dashboard

Answer (score 0):

If you're load testing a **server** it doesn't make any difference for it where the request is coming from. In case you need to check how does the server behave under the load and what response time for different geo-locations look like you can do it manually using i.e. [Amazon Micro instances](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/09/09/announcing-micro-instances-for-amazon-ec2) which are free.

In case you don't want the manual steps you can run JMeter in [distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/) using a helper script like [JMeter ec2](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) which automates deployment of JMeter slaves onto AWS machines but be prepared to higher [connect time and latency](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) metrics